# SQL - it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE FROM
    BKC_Menu_Analysis.dbo.vw_HourlySales_2020
WHERE
    CAST( BizDate AS date ) >= '02/21/2022'
```

This is the Code I am trying to do and get the error below,

> Msg 4403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot update the view or function
> 'BKC_Menu_Analysis.dbo.vw_HourlySales_2020' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.

I am trying to delete dates after 2.21.22 In the database, any help?

Comment: Delete from the table, not the view?

Answer (score 0):

The error you have received means that your view is not updatable. There are [several conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views) that a view must satisfy for DML operations to be allowed on it.

If you can't/don't want to make your view conform to those conditions, you have two ways to go:

1. Perform DML operations on the underlaying table instead
2. Define `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the view to handle DML operations manually.

If you provide the code for your view, it will be possible for the community to help you write such trigger.